# Show two images overlapping each other in openCV

Tags: c++, image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

In Matlab there is a possibility to show two images overlapping each other, which is quite useful to show how two images are aligned with respect to each other.

For instance look to following code:

```
img1 = zeros(100,100);
img1(20:50, 10:40) = 255;
img2 = zeros(100, 100);
img2(35:65, 35:65) = 255;
imshowpair(img1, img2);
```

which creates following image:

[image]

Is there any built-in function or any way in openCV library to do so (in c++)?

Comment: this may help: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `addWeighted` as documented [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html)

```
Mat img1 = Mat(100,100,CV_8UC3,Scalar::all(0));
Mat img2 = Mat(100,100,CV_8UC3,Scalar::all(0));
rectangle(img1, Rect(20,10,50,40), Scalar(0,255,0), -1);
rectangle(img2, Rect(35,35,65,65), Scalar(255,0,255), -1);
Mat result;
addWeighted(img1, 0.5, img2, 0.5, 0.0, result);
imshow("SO question", result);
waitKey(10);
```

Comment: I was looking for an exact way of image representation as good as what matlab does.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `imshowpair` so I don't know the full range of what it does, but in this case it looks like it's simply taking the first image as the green channel and the second image as the blue and red channels:

```
cv::Mat img1 = cv::Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8U);
rectangle(img1, cv::Rect(10,20,30,30), 255, CV_FILLED);

cv::Mat img2 = cv::Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8U);
rectangle(img2, cv::Rect(35,35,30,30), 255, CV_FILLED);

std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::Mat imgPair;

channels.push_back(img2);
channels.push_back(img1);
channels.push_back(img2);

merge(channels, imgPair);

imshow("imgPair", imgPair);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Output:

[image: imgPair result]

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which is working when you want to use openCV library only in debug mode:

```
void showImagePairs(const cv::Mat &img1, const cv::Mat &img2) {

    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
    cv::Mat imgPair;

    channels.push_back(img2);
    channels.push_back(img1);
    channels.push_back(img2);

    cv::merge(&channels[0], channels.size(), imgPair);

    cv::imshow("imgPair", imgPair);

    int c = cvWaitKey(40);

}
```

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure how that's any different from my answer, but it's good you got it working, I guess.

Comment: The difference is when you want to run your code in "debug" or "release" mode. Using your code it was giving me exception and I only have release .lib files from opencv (I compiled library only for release mode)!

Comment: It's really a trivial change. Some feedback would have been welcome. Failing that, some attribution would have been appropriate.

Comment: Sure it is trivial, and of course it is basically coming from your answer.